# complex logic on pyspark dataframe including previous row existing value as well as previous row value generated on the fly

Tags: pyspark

I have to apply a logic on spark dataframe or rdd(preferably dataframe) which requires to generate two extra column. First generated column is dependent on other columns of same row and second generated column is dependent on first generated column of previous row.

Below is representation of problem statement in tabular format. A and B columns are available in dataframe. C and D columns are to be generated.

```
A |  B   | C            |     D
------------------------------------
1 | 100  |  default val |    C1-B1
2 | 200  |  D1-C1       |    C2-B2
3 | 300  |  D2-C2       |    C3-B3
4 | 400  |  D3-C3       |    C4-B4
5 | 500  |  D4-C4       |    C5-B5
```

Here is the sample data

```
A |  B   |    C   |   D
------------------------
1 | 100  |   1000 |  900
2 | 200  |  -100  | -300
3 | 300  |  -200  | -500
4 | 400  |  -300  | -700
5 | 500  |  -400  | -900
```

Only solution I can think of is to coalesce the input dataframe to 1, convert it to rdd and then apply python function (having all the calcuation logic) to mapPartitions API .
However this approach may create load on one executor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lag() function may help you with that:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w =  Window.orderBy("A")

df1 = df1.withColumn("C", F.lit(1000))

df2 = (
      df1
     .withColumn("D", F.col("C") - F.col("B"))
     .withColumn("C", 
                  F.when(F.lag("C").over(w).isNotNull(), 
                         F.lag("D").over(w) - F.lag("C").over(w))
                   .otherwise(F.col("C")))
     .withColumn("D", F.col("C") - F.col("B"))
)
```

Comment: In this solution, during calculation of D, value of C is fixed to 1000 for all rows. However in problem statement, column C of row 2 is dependent on column D of row 1. Also one over(w) is missing in third last line of your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on missing code. Explaining why I fixed 1000 for all rows, it is the default_value setted in the first row, after that the column C is calculated again with subsequent values. Anyway, if you want to calculate something using the previous value of a column the lag() function may help.

Comment: I have executed this code. Data for column D generated by this code is  900,800,700,600,500 however desired output for column D is 900,-300,-500,-700,-900, This is happening because above code is considering default value of C for all rows while doing column D calculation. Also one more small code change in line 4 from top. You need to assign the output dataframe to df1 again.

Comment: after following the comment of @Raghu from another answer, we need to calculate column D again after calculating column C.This way we will have desired answer.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically seeing, D1-C1 where D1= C1-B1; so D1-C1 will become C1-B1-C1 => -B1.
In pyspark, window function has a parameter called default. this should simplify your problem. try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,100),(2,200),(3,300),(4,400),(5,500)],['a','b'])
w=Window.orderBy('a')
df_lag =df.withColumn('c',F.lag((F.col('b')*-1),default=1000).over(w))
df_final = df_lag.withColumn('d',F.col('c')-F.col('b'))
```

Results:

```
df_final.show()
+---+---+----+----+
|  a|  b|   c|   d|
+---+---+----+----+
|  1|100|1000| 900|
|  2|200|-100|-300|
|  3|300|-200|-500|
|  4|400|-300|-700|
|  5|500|-400|-900|
+---+---+----+----+
```

If the operation is something complex other than subtraction, then the same logic applies - fill the column C with your default value- calculate D , then use lag to calculate C and recalculate D.

Comment: The calculation shown in problem statement is for representation purpose. Actual calculation is not simple subtraction. I want a solution which can implement dependency of previous generated column which is D in above table.

Comment: @PrateekPathak - you can apply the same logic also for any calculation.  fill the column C with your default value- calculate d , then use lag to calculate C and recalculate D

Comment: Yes it worked. Your comment which I have upvoted is the gist of the solution. I have taken the code provided by Thales Souto and modify it as per comment.

Comment: @PrateekPathak - happy to hear. upvotes to comments are not visible to me. If the answer has helped, can you upvote and accept the answer so that it is useful for others in the future?(No obligation) I will also update the answer to include the comment.